# Why I am getting error HTTP GET method not supported by this URL, while I am not using it anywhere in my code

Tags: java, servlets

I am developing login servlet app my code is as follows:

**Login page** for displaying two text box and one login button. Where user enter username and password and submit data.

```
public class LoginPage extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
         String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
            out.println("<form method='post' action='LoginCheck'>");
            out.println("Username: <input type='text' name='username'>");
            out.println("<br>");
            out.println("Password: <input type='password' name='password'>");
            out.println("<br>");
            out.println("<input type='submit' value='login'>");
            out.println("<br>");
        out.println("</form>");
    }
}
```

**LoginCheck page** This page is for checking user's username and password.After checking if username and password is correct then it redirect to **welcome** page or if it is incorrect then it redirects to **Error** page And the code for each page is as follows:

```
public class LoginCheck extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        if(username.equals("abs") && password.equals("abs")){
            response.sendRedirect("Welcome");
        }else{
            response.sendRedirect("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

**Welcome** If username and password correct.

```
public class Welcome extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<h3>Welcome user</h3>");
    }
}
```

**Error** If username or password is Incorrect.

```
public class ErrorPage extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<h3>ERROR !!!</h3>");
        out.println("<h3>Username or Password you entered is wrong.</h3>");
    }
}
```

OK !!! But after entering username and password to login page it goes to checklogin and when it goes towards welcome page or error page it gives error !!!

> HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

I am not using `GET` method anywhere in above code as you can see but why I am getting this type of error ???

Comment: You send a redirect - this instructs the browser that the page has moved (HTTP 302). The browser then uses a `GET` to get the new page. But either your `Error` nor your `Welcome` pages support `GET`.

Comment: So what can I do now to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Support GET in your servlets. Or [don't use a redirect](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagi.html).

Comment: So is their any option instead redirect ?

Comment: Please read the links people give you before bothering them.

Comment: If you must use `POST`, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550752/send-post-request-in-java-with-response-sendredirect-method) question, but you are not posting any data to the servlet, so you really shouldn't be using `POST`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you get HTTP 405 is that [HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) is specified like this:

> Sends a temporary redirect response to the client using the specified
>   redirect location URL.

So if you do a `response.sendRedirect("Welcome");`, you "tell" the client browser to go to the relative URL "Welcome" instead. This by coincidence is mapped to your `Welcome`-servlet (I presume). HTTP only supports GET redirects, so a GET request is issued by the client browser, but your `Welcome`-servlet only supports POST.

If you change your `Welcome`-servlert like this it should work:

```
public class Welcome extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<h3>Welcome user</h3>");
    }
}
```

Remember to change your `ErrorPage`-servlet as well.

**BUT heed the following!**

You should not use a client side redirect but a server side forward like this:

```
public class LoginCheck extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        if(username.equals("abs") && password.equals("abs")){
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }else{
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Error");
            rd.forward(request, response);            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After using ` RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome");
            rd.forward(request, response);` That works. :) but can you explain why is that happening here ???

Comment: @AbhijitKumbhar have you read the link I gave you or are you still defiantly ignoring it? Please stop asking to be spoonfed and do some reading. You are never going to learn to be a skilled programmer if you cannot read simple documentation.

Comment: Sorry @BoristheSpider I didn't recognized your link, But now I read that and I understand Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

to

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

in you Welcome and Error methods.
Thanks [Andrew Mairose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2561365/andrew-mairose) for pointing that out in comments.

Reference - http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=j601/demolet.java

Comment: Don't you mean the other way around?

Comment: @AbhijitKumbhar see my comment. You do use `GET`, of course.

Comment: But what if I want to use `post`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)

sendRedirect method is URL redirect which means a GET method on the url.

Comment: Why do you want to use `POST`? You shouldn't use `POST` if you are not posting any data to the servlet.