# Spring, redirect to external url using POST

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redirect

In the following Spring 3.1 action, I've to do some stuff and add attribute to a POST request, and then redirect it to external URL through POST (I can't use GET).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/selectCUAA", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView selectCUAA(@RequestParam(value="userID", required=true) String cuaa, ModelMap model) {
    //query & other...
    model.addAttribute(PARAM_NAME_USER, cuaa);
    model.addAttribute(... , ...);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:http://www.externalURL.com/", model);
}
```

But with this code the GET method is used (the attributes are appended to http://www.externalURL.com/). How can I use the POST method? It's mandatory from the external URL.

Comment: Then it isn't a redirect. A redirect always results in a GET request. If you want a POST you will have to call the URL from the java code and pass the result along.

Comment: See also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like @stepanian said, you can't redirect with POST.
But there are few workarounds:

1. Do a simple HttpUrlConnection and use POST. After output the response stream. It works, but I had some problem with CSS.
2. Do stuff in your controller and after redirect the result data to a fake page. This page will do automatically the POST through javascript with no user interaction ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550752/send-post-request-in-java-with-response-sendredirect-method)):

html:

```
<form name="myRedirectForm" action="https://processthis.com/process" method="post">
    <input name="name" type="hidden" value="xyz" />
    <input name="phone" type="hidden" value="9898989898" />
    <noscript>
        <input type="submit" value="Click here to continue" />
    </noscript>
</form>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            document.myRedirectForm.submit();
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: here's another example that backs this up, i liked this util class https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/b478472b3578b8980d7b5f1642e91e75d1e78d16/common/src/main/java/org/keycloak/common/util/HttpPostRedirect.java

Answer (score 3):

You can't redirect with POST. You can send a POST request using Java code with a class like [HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) within the action.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I used this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java my Spring controller *selectCUAA* what should return now? I need a redirect to the new web page.

Comment: You can redirect after the code-envoked POST is completed.

Comment: Redirect with no attribute? In this way is it like calling a post and after a get, so the result will be only the last get? (the new url is a login page that need the parameter on post).
However thanks, monday I will give a try

Comment: You can get the response from the post and return it to the user in the get response.

Comment: I gave a look on the internet, but I become more confused. Could you show me an example modifying my *selectCUAA* controller?