# Keep request body when redirect to an external URL

Tags: java, json, url, spring-boot, request

In my Spring Boot project I must have a postmapping which has a JSON in request body:

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/cloudapi/**")
    public String postCloud(HttpServletRequest request,
                            HttpServletResponse response,
                            Model model) {
        String[] urlparts = request.getRequestURI().split("/cloudapi");
        String urltail = "";

        if (urlparts.length > 1)
            urltail = urlparts[1];

        return "rango:8075/cloudapi" + urltail;
    }
```

`postCloud(...)` method should forward the request to an external URL(*"rango:8075/cloudapi"*). The problem is it is losing its body when redirect.

JSON in request body:

```
{
  "sm": -12,
  "customerid": "asd123"
}
```

Content-Type is application/json.

Server port from application.properties:

```
server.port=8081
```

> How can I save the request body while I forward it? Or is it possible
>   to set that JSON as request body when redirect to an external URL?

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-forward-vs-httpservletresponse-sendredirect?

Comment: I tried both RequestDispatcher and SendRedirect, but couldn't figure out how keep JSON in request body.

Comment: One more useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353528/spring-redirect-to-external-url-using-post